# What does the partial trace of an operator tell me about the full operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, multilinear-algebra, trace

I have a situation where I would like to know something about an operator when I know something about its partial trace.

Let $A$ be a trace class operator on $H\otimes H$, nonnegative, of trace one, and symmetric in the sense that 
$$P_S\,A\,P_S=A\,,$$
where $P_S$ is the projection onto the subspace of symmetric vectors in $H\otimes H$. ($H$ is a possibly infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.)

Let $a$ be the partial trace of $A$. I know  that $a$ is almost the orthogonal projection $p_v$ on a unit vector $v$ in $H$:
$$Tr|a-p_v|\ll 1\,.$$

I would like to prove that
$$Tr|A-p_v\otimes p_v|\ll 1\,.$$
Does anybody have any ideas about how to show this?

Comment: What do you mean by the absolute value bar in the trace? Do you mean take component wise absolute value?

Comment: I mean $|B|:=\sqrt{B^* B}$, where the square root $\sqrt{C}$ of a nonnegative matrix $C$ is the only nonnegative matrix such that $\sqrt{C}^2=C$. (And by $C$ nonnegative I mean $\langle u,C u\rangle\geq 0$ for all vector $u$.)

Well if you prefer $Tr|\cdot|$ is the trace norm.